# Заработок на своем сайте

Tags: seo

Здравствуйте. Кто имеет опыт заработка на своих сайтах, подскажите сколько нужно пользователей в день для того, чтобы с него можно было что-то заработать? Планируется сайт на несколько тысяч пользователей в день. Достаточно ли этого, чтобы зарабатывать хотя бы на оплату хостинга (10$ в месяц), ну и на пиво желательно))

Ах да, пользователи будут перимущественно с мобильных устройств. Имеет ли это значение?

Немножко покурил форумы и добавлю: страниц будет пару штук (около 5). При каждом входе вероятно юзер пройдет все - что-то типа мастера, а потом результат. Я так понял это сильно влияет на заработок (кол-во страниц сайта).

П.С. Благодарю за любые советы и грабли, на которые вы сами наступали, т.к. это будет мой(не только) проект "для людей". Сам об этом всем понятия не имею. Знаю только, что зарботать можно на рекламе...

Comment: ТС ну расскажите, удалось собрать 1000 уников на пятистраничнике? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо конкретно смотреть, что за пользователи в этих нескольких тысячах и подбирать методы монетизации. Но даже если это будет мусорный траф, то 20 баксов в месяц вы отработаете точно. Самое сложное найти эти 1-2 тыс. посетителей в сутки. Когда получите такой трафик, приходите, задавайте конкретные вопросы, подскажем как монетизировать.

Comment: @Максим36, спасибо. Действительно, когда запущу сайт и соберу статистику, тогда и спрошу совета. А пока просто хотел определиться стоит ли вообще запускать или нет. Еще 10 месяцев есть халявного хостинга. Можно еще подумать.

Answer (score 2):

Если несколько тысяч пользователей, то хостинг и на пиво вы в любом случае отобьете. "Насколько больше" уже зависит от сайта и способа монетизации.

Answer (score 2):

Если без sap'ы, то с 500 хостов в день можно рубить от 15 баков в месяц (допустим файлообменник и гугл эдсенс), 
как только нарастите PR и ТИЦ примерно 2 и 20, то + еще 15-20 баков в месяца с sap'ы

Comment: @unlike777, читал, что в сапу надо от 30 страниц контента вроде. Их будет несколько - около 5.

Comment: нет не обязательно, основной упор делается на главную страницу, потому что она несет самый большой ТИЦ и PR даже если у тебя будет много страниц, основной доход будет все-равно с главной...

Comment: @unlike, хм, спасибо. Учту при разработке.

Comment: Какой смысл в сапу пихать 5-страничник, тем более с посещалкой в 1-2 тыс. человек? Это только проект позорить продажными ссылками.

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас будет действительно хорошая посещаемость, то, впринципе, можно будет оплачивать клики по рекламе - главное не переборщить.
Если делать все грамотно, то доход можно и под сотню сделать

Comment: @Stas0n, спасибо. Я решил: запущу проект, соберу народ, соберу статистику, а потом и буду задавать вопросы конкретнее) спасибо.

Comment: будут вопросы, пиши в скайп: stas0n19

Comment: слушай, как статистику собирешь - пришли мне, если не секрет)
просто интересно как там и что)